# When this URL(/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx) gets called

Tags: solr, sitecore-client, azure, sitecore-api

We have deployed `Sitecore` into the `Azure cloud`. We often see `Sitecore CM` instance getting down, to fix this slowness check the `http5xxx error` on the azure web APP. As part of troubleshooting noticed `500  server error`(`/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx`) this URL post and get request returning `500 error`. I would like to understand when this Search,ashx gets called and how to resolve it.

If anyone experiences this error please let me know.
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

Buckets/Services/Search.ashx is a Sitecore's internal service handler to perform the search in Search Tab, This can be used for bucket items or regular items. It communicates with `Sitecore_master_index` index and returns JSON object.
[image]